# I want to add rows in all table with the name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I want to add some rows in the tables but they have the same name. I've got the individual row length of the 3 tables but when i insert the row, it only inserted in the first table.  Here is my code using javascript:

```
$('table').each(function() {
    var sam = $('tbody tr', this).length;
        var table = document.getElementById("tb-calendar1");

        // alert(sam);
        if(sam < 8){
            var row = table.insertRow(7);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);

            cell1.innerHTML = " ";
            cell2.innerHTML = " ";
            cell3.innerHTML = " ";
            cell4.innerHTML = " ";
            cell5.innerHTML = " ";
            cell6.innerHTML = " ";
            cell7.innerHTML = " ";
                    }
    });
```

Here's the picture
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the HTML to the question. I ask as it seems as through you've repeated the same `id` multiple times, which is invalid and would cause the behaviour you describe

Comment: Your jQuery is for each `table` element, but inside you always select the table element with id `tb-calendar1`. I'd needs to be unique for each element on the page. But maybe you really want `$(this)`.

Comment: yes i hope that i can put different ID's but i used calendar library and just get it through the **model**  and i don't know how i will separate it individually. But thank you so much sirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have table elements with duplicate email IDs. IDs must be unique. Due to duplicate ids, your selector for table(`document.getElementById`) is selecting first table only.

You can rather use context `this` to target current table element in `.each()`.

```
var table = this;
```

Comment: woaaahhh it works :O ...  actually i use earlier `var table = $(this); `  but it doesn't work...so this is how to do it!!!! thank you ^_^

Comment: It did not worked because `.insertRow` is Javascript function. using javascript methods/properties on jquery object would throw error. Glad it helps :)